# Executes Input statement straight away, need to do an if statement

Tags: python

I'm working through some code that I have to do as apart of a course, and a piece of code I have to write includes an input for the user. However when I write that part of the code out, it executes it straight away and doesn't let me finish writing the code. It needs an if statement in order to execute properly.

This is the code

```
today = input("What day is it?")
if today == "Monday":
   dayOfWeek = 1
elif today == "Tuesday":
   dayOfWeek = 2
elif today == "Wednesday":
   dayOfWeek = 3 
elif today == "Thursday":
   dayOfWeek = 4
elif today == "Friday":
   dayOfWeek = 5
elif today == "Saturday":
   dayOfWeek = 6
elif today == "Sunday":
   dayOfWeek = 7
else:
   print("That’s not a valid week day!")
```

I've even tried putting a \ after the first line but then I just get an syntax error warning.

Comment: Are you doing this directly in the console? If so, save it as a file first such as `test.py` and then run it as an executable file from the console instead like so  `python test.py`. However, I don't fully understand you question so I may have misunderstood what the problem you are facing actually is...

Comment: I dont understand your question john doe ...

Comment: Sorry it's not very understandable! I am in the python shell, and that is the code that I need to write out. However, when I type the today = input("What day is it?") it immediately prints out underneath 'What day is it?' and I am unable to continue the code, I would like to know how I am able to continue the code and then execute it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the console isn't waiting for your input. Is that correct?

That being said, the above code works fine for me. It might be an issue with the file settings - try copy/pasting into a new file and run it there.